# Sequential coupling in code

Tags: oop, anti-patterns

Is [sequential coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling) really a bad thing in code?

Although it's an anti-pattern, the only risk I see is calling methods in the wrong order but documentation of an API/class library with this anti-pattern should take care of that. What other problems are there from code which is sequential? Also, this pattern could easily be fixed by using a facade it seems.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that wiki page goes so far as to say they are bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even in Wiki article you mentioned there is an opinion that

> This may be an anti-pattern, **depending on context**.

In many cases there is no other way. Eventually we use **algorithms** to solve tasks. And they are by definition

> an effective methods for solving a problem using a finite **sequence** of instructions

Sometimes it's possible to hide this sequence. But not always.

Answer (score 5):

It is an antipattern to *just ignore* a method call because something which shouldn't have been done before hasn't.

This should be controlled using **design by contract**. Failed preconditions typically raise a **failed precondition exception**, which is basically the software yelling at you if you use the class in the wrong way. They are superior to written documentation.

Answer (score 1):

its a minor anti pattern, as if the documentation is bad (or the api is confusing) you can get things into a bad states. Its like a recipe where it only tells you to put the yolks aside after you've already beaten the eggs together.

Answer (score 0):

If the class does not do network communication, it is a minor antipattern. Whether it is an antipattern and what the solution is (builder pattern, look for a declarative solution, see if you can use a union-find structure, etc etc or just keep the interface and add validation steps to the methods) varies depending on context.

If the class performs network communication, then it can easily escalate to very bad/major performance issue by forcing network delays and complex concurrency handling on you, and it can be a symptom of a broader architectural problem like coupling between services.